# Can I wire multiple brushless motors in series or parallel?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, pmsm

EDIT: As Bruce Abbott pointed out in his answer, it's not possible to connect 3-wire brushless motors in series, since you don't have access to both ends of each winding. Oops. So, the more relevant question is whether there are any potential problems with wiring multiple motors in *parallel*, other than the increased current draw.

ORIGINAL QUESTION: I'm working on a design that requires a large amount of torque in a very confined space. Due to this and other requirements, my best options seems to be to use two motors to drive a single load. The shafts would be connected together, so the two motors would always maintain the same relative orientation.

I would like to avoid using two motor controllers, so I'm thinking of wiring each phase of the two motors in series (i.e. phase 1 of motor A is in series with phase 1 of motor B, etc.). I would have a single encoder on one of the motors, which I would be using for position feedback and for sinusoidal commutation. I'm expecting that this would effectively allow the two motors to act as a single larger motor, with double the voltage required for a given speed. Is there any reason this wouldn't work, or any potential issues I need to watch out for?

One thing I'm worried about is that I would need to make sure that the connection between the two motor shafts is "clocked" correctly such that the rotors of both motors have the same position relative to the stator windings. There will inevitably be some error in this; I assume that this would just slightly reduce the torque for a given amount of current, but perhaps it would cause other issues?

Some additional information, in case it affects the answer:

1. This is for a positioning application which uses a haptic operator interface. This uses the motor current to calculate the motor torque, which is then used to provide force feedback to the operator. Therefore, one of the main requirements is very low torque ripple.
2. The motor speed will be very low (from 0-100 RPM).
3. The motors I would be using are the EC-4pole motors from Maxon.
4. I will likely be using the EPOS4 motor controllers from Maxon.

Comment: Why can't you pick a single motor to replace the two motors? You say small space, okay, but longer motors of the same diameter should exist.

Comment: Will you be driving these with a controlled current, or with a constant voltage?  If the command out of your controller is for current, you can just run two encoders and two motor drives, and gang the motors together any which way.  Or just get a bigger motor.

Comment: @DKNguyen: If they exist, I haven't been able to find them. The Maxon EC-4pole motors are already a very long, narrow motor (32 mm diameter, 142 mm long, not including the shaft or encoder). I'm certainly open to suggestions, though! My choices are somewhat constrained by the fact that I'm looking for a motor with an ironless core, to eliminate cogging torque (see point #1 in my question). I was considering the Maxon EC-i52, which has a 52mm diameter and can provide enough torque, but it has an iron core and therefore suffers from cogging torque.

Comment: That already is pretty long. Well, should be easy enough to align the rotors. Connect the phase wires in parallel and then feed current through two phases with a controlled source so the rotors lock but don't burn out and while its lock clamp both rotors together.

Comment: @TimWescott: Current will be the controlled variable. Yes, I could certainly run two encoders and two drives, but I'd like to avoid this if possible, both to reduce expense and, more importantly, the number of wires that I have to run (the wires will probably be going through a slip ring, and I already have quite a lot of wires to deal with).

Comment: @DKNguyen: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: *large torque in confined space at low speed* I hope using gears has been explored. Should shift the attention from *motor* torque ripple, too. There is more than helical planetary gears - harmonic gears, for one.

Answer (score 1):

> so I'm thinking of wiring each phase of the two motors in series (i.e.
> phase 1 of motor A is in series with phase 1 of motor B, etc.)

To wire the phases in series you need access to both ends of each winding. Maxon EC-4 motors only have 3 external phase wires and no way to separate the windings internally, so you cannot wire them in series.

However you *can* wire identical brushless motors in parallel, so long as you match the rotor angles precisely and the shafts are tightly coupled. Use the encoder from one motor only and the pair will act like a single motor.

In parallel the total maximum current will be doubled, and your controller will have have to handle twice the current of a single motor. So choose high voltage motors whose combined current doesn't exceed the controller's rating.

Comment: Good point; in retrospect, that should have been obvious, but clearly I didn't think it through well enough. I had considered wiring in parallel, but wanted to avoid the extra current draw since it will exceed the continuous rating of the controller I was planning to use. Oh well, perhaps I can find a different one.

Comment: I was also a bit worried about unbalanced current draw if the shaft angles aren't perfectly matched, but it sounds like you think it's feasible to match the angles well enough that this won't be a problem? Do you think the method mentioned by DKNguyen (supply current to the same phase of both motors, then couple the shafts together) is the best way to do that? I can't think of a better method, but clearly I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @ChrisGraham I would jiggle the shafts while locked a bit to make sure they aren't sticking a bit off center. In self-calibrating systems, I've found that getting rotors to lock in position under their own power doesn't always result in them being centered over the pole.

Comment: @DKNguyen: good advice, thanks.

Comment: _"wanted to avoid the extra current draw since it will exceed the continuous rating of the controller I was planning to use."_ - exactly which motors and controller were you planning to use?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment earlier. I'm planning to use the Maxon EC-4pole Ø32 mm motor (part #393879) and the Maxon EPOS4 70/15 controller (part #594385). I'm looking for about 1.5 Nm of continuous torque, which I should be able to get from 2 motors with 11.3 A per motor. This exceeds the continuous rated torque and will require that I reduce the case/ambient thermal resistance to below 0.4 K/W. Even at 0 K/W, a single motor could only give 0.98 Nm continuously. The controller can only do 15 A continuously, so not enough for both motors in parallel. _continued below_

Comment: The controller can do 30A for 60 seconds, so perhaps I can provide additional cooling to the controller to extend its continuous current to the 22.6A that I need. I'm open to other options, but I do need something that's EtherCAT compatible and offers cyclic synchronous torque.

I should also mention that I was originally planning to use the Maxon EC-i 52 (part #667063), which should be sufficient on its own. But it has an iron core, and I am worried that the cogging torque (even though Maxon claims it is "very low") will cause problems, since this will be used in a haptic feedback device.

Comment: If it can handle 30A for 1 minute then it should do 22.6A for much longer, because heating is proportional to current squared. Exactly which motor were you looking at, and how much torque do you need?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: I had to split my previous comment into two parts since it exceeded the length limit. It looks like you missed the first part where I gave the part numbers and torque requirements. Sorry, I should have put a note saying "part 2" or something like that.